# Reliable way to track Page Index in a UIPageViewController - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, containers, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I have a UIPageViewController (custom one) inside a Container located in a regular UIViewController. i need to be able to call an event with each Page Change but ONLY if it really did change and not only half way or anything of that sort.

using:

```
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
```

is unreliable and not called each time for some reason.

if your answer contains anything about willTransitionToViewControllers or didFinishAnimating please elaborate and not just mention them, since i already know they exist but dont understand the proper way to use them.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `didFinishAnimating` it has a `completed` and `finished` property so you know the page has actually changed. From the pageViewController you can get the currently displayed page, then get the position of this VC in your model.

First make sure your ViewController adopts `UIPageViewControllerDelegate`

Set the delegate (e.g. in `viewDidLoad`)

```
pageViewController.delegate = self
```

Then implement the following function:

```
    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
        if (completed && finished) {
            if let currentVC = pageViewController.viewControllers?.last {
                let index = myViewControllers.indexOf(currentVC)
                //do something with index
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so very much James, it solved my problem :) in case any other beginners find this solution: dont forget to add UIPageViewControllerDelegate at the class declaration to allow this function to be called.

Comment: No worries, I've added your comment to the answer.

Comment: appreciate it James :)

Comment: What is the value of "myViewControllers", and how to set it?

Comment: When would the viewControllers array ever contain more than 1?

Comment: @ScriptKitty One reason would be if the spineLocation is set to `mid`.